# Conditional probability sample space

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I was solving a probability question. Here are the screenshots for the problem.
[image: First]

[image: Second]

I want to know , In the second image when  we are calculating P(D | E1) , why it is being divided by 100. The sample space for E1 is 25% , then why are we dividing by 100.

*P( D | E1)  = P( D intersection E1)/ P( E1)*

Why don't we use this formula here?

I have tried to ask on many forums but still could not clear my doubt.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Note that $\Pr(D \mid E_1)$ is the probability that a bolt is defective given that it is produced by machine $A$.  We are given that $\Pr(D \mid E_1) = 5\% = \frac{5}{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathsf P(D\mid E_1)$ is the probability that a bolt is defective given that it is produced by factory $A$.

You are *told* that "of their respective outputs $\bf 5\%$, $4\%$, and $2\%$ are defective".

Hence these are the probabilities that a bolt is defective when given that it is from a specified factory.

Thus no calculation is required. $\qquad$ $\mathsf P(D\mid E_1)=5\%\\\mathsf P(D\mid E_2)=4\%\\\mathsf P(D\mid E_3)=2\%$

Comment: @ Graham Kemp...then why it's being done this way in the solution?